# Tag synonym request: repeating-reboot and boot-loop

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The new tag[repeating-reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeating-reboot) should become a synonym of [boot-loop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot-loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed and done. Thanks for catching that.